# Why can't gcc find the random() interface when -std=c99 is set?

Tags: c, gcc, random, c99, c89

I do `"#include <stdlib.h>"` at the top of the source.

Example compilation:

```
/usr/bin/colorgcc -std=c99 -fgnu89-inline  -g -Wall -I/usr/include -I./ -I../ -I../../ -I../../../ -I../../../../    -O3 -o f8  f8.c
In file included from f8.c:7:
ctype-cmp.c: In function ‘randomized’:
ctype-cmp.c:48: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘random’
ctype-cmp.c: In function ‘main’:
ctype-cmp.c:153: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘srandom’
ais@xcalibur:t$
```

When I turn off -std=c99, the function isfinite() can not be found.  So I do want to use -std=c99 for this and other reasons. Is there some trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`man srandom` says that the function is *not* part of C99 but part of POSIX.

Activate `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500` or any other suitable feature test macro that declares the srandom/random function (see `man feature_test_macros` and `man srandom`).

This one has good chances, but you need to figure out the macros that are defined/not defined implicitly thereby too by reading the manpages above.

```
/usr/bin/colorgcc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -fgnu89-inline -g -Wall 
    -I/usr/include -I./ -I../ -I../../ -I../../../ -I../../../../ -O3 -o f8  f8.c
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is a trick you are missing: you can use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99`.

`-std=c99` `#define`s `__STRICT_ANSI__`, which `/usr/include/features.h` interprets as "do not enable anything outside the C standard by default" (without it, you get at least both `_SVID_SOURCE` and `_BSD_SOURCE`). `-std=gnu99`, on the other hand, means "C99 plus GNU extensions" (the gcc default is currently `-std=gnu89`, its C89 equivalent, which is why you needed to specify something to get the new C99 features).

As an alternative, you can enable the feature test macros (as mentioned in @litb's answer). Looking at `/usr/include/stdlib.h` in my system, it expects one of `__USE_SVID`, `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED`, or `__USE_BSD`. `/usr/include/features.h` tells me that the feature test macros which would enable these are:

- `_SVID_SOURCE` (enables `__USE_SVID`)
- `_BSD_SOURCE` (enables `__USE_BSD`)
- `_XOPEN_SOURCE` with a value of at least `500` (enables `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED`)
- `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` (also enables `__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED`)
- `_GNU_SOURCE` (enables everything, including the four feature test macros above)

For new programs where you are not too concerned about potential name collisions with new functions from future standards, using both `-std=gnu99` and `-D_GNU_SOURCE` is a good idea. It allows you to use all the new standard features and GNU extensions, which combined with some sort of fallback (for instance, `autoconf`-style feature tests) gives the most flexibility.

References:

- [Options Controlling C Dialect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)
- [Feature Test Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've created random numbers using gcc in CodeBlocks under Ubuntu 9.10 (with compiler options: `-std=gnu99 -D_GNU_SOURCE`) So this worked for me:

This is my code I had played with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
enum computer {keyboard, CPU, screen, printer};
int main(void)
{
  enum computer comp;
  time_t casovac;
  comp = CPU;
  srand(&casovac);
  printf("%d", rand());
  return 0;
}
```

This was only idea, of course you can accomplish it by other ways ;-) [To install CodeBlocks use: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then `sudo apt-get install codeblocks`]

Answer (score -1):

I use rand() and srand(). BTW: Did you forget a header or two? At least the second warning tells me so.

Try including math.h. (Just remembered we always had issues with math library and had to actually force link it with -lm).

Comment: I had to down vote this response since correct header's were included (both stdlib and math).  The trick was defining the macro.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I didn't see you had mentioned math.h

Comment: As a total C noob, I appreciated the mention of `srand` at least. Thanks!