# Can -std=c99 prevent my #includes from working properly?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to compile a C program on a Linux system. I have an `#include` statement for `stdlib.h`.

When I compile the program with `gcc` as follows:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -o progfoo progfoo.c progbar.c
```

I get warnings about `Implicit declaration of function [srand48, drand48, bzero, or close]`.

Compiling instead as:

```
gcc -g -o progfoo progfoo.c progbar.c
```

doesn't give me the warnings, but it does yell about my use of `for` loops (which was the rationale for adding `-std=c99` in the first place).

Given that `man srand48` mentions including `<stdlib.h>`, which I have, I'm unsure what else the problem could be. The `for` loops aren't essential to anything (they were just to save time in initializing an array) so I have no problem removing them, but before I do I'd like to confirm whether the `c99` standard is superseding some aspect of my `#include` statements.

I'm using `gcc 4.1.2-50 (Red Hat)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can -std=c99 prevent my #includes from working properly?

No, but they may show up limitations in your *knowledge* of how they work :-)

---

While the functions `[sd]rand48` have a prototype in `stdlib.h`, they're inside an `#ifdef`, at least on my system:

```
#if defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_XOPEN
```

So you will probably have to explicitly set one of those macros.

However, before you try it, be aware that it doesn't work. That's because all this stuff is controlled with `gcc`'s [feature test macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

There's a very complicated set of rules used to set specific features on or off in `features.h` and the macros created there control what the header files include and exclude. The `__USE_*` variants are cleared and set in that header file based on *other* macros provided by yourself.

For example, to get `__USE_SVID` set so you can use `srand48`, you need to provide the compiler with a `-D_SVID_SOURCE` parameter.

But perhaps an easier way is to just use C99 with the GNU extensions. To do that, replace `-std=c99` with `-std=gnu99`.

And, for `bzero` and `close`, these can be obtained from `strings.h` and `unistd.h` respectively.

I was a little confused at first as to why these compiled with `-std=c99` when they have absolutely *nothing* to do with C99 but then I realised that flag only controls what the *standard C headers* give you.

Neither `strings.h` (note the plural name, this is *not* `string.h`) nor `unistd.h` are part of ISO C.

Comment: Good point, @Matteo, I tend to think of _macros_ as the ones that _do_ things, like `#define halfOf(x) ((x) / 2)`, as opposed to just "flags" to control compilation. But you're correct and the use of the work "variable" by myself is apt to lead to confusion with real variables. So I changed it as per your suggestion.

Comment: Right.  It might be helpful to know that when you compile with no `-std=` flag, you are asking for `-std=gnu89`, which is C89 plus GNU extensions - so the C99 equivalent to this mode is `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: It is better to learn how to enable POSIX extensions in the standard way, because messing with `__USE_SVID` or `__USE_XOPEN` are inherently unportable.  They work on some machines (probably Linux-ish), but won't work on other machines.  Using `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` or `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` is better - hence [Kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/458988/kevin)'s answer is the better solution.

Comment: Normally, I'd agree but, since the tags specifically stated Linux and the question stated RedHat, I assumed portability wasn't of great importance.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the functions that you are using are not ISO C99, so when you request
strict C99 compliance they will not be visible.

Information here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=130815

The flag `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` should work.

See also this question: [Why can't gcc find the random() interface when -std=c99 is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575350/why-cant-gcc-find-the-random-interface-when-std-c99-is-set)

Comment: Just like I have to make a function prototype for "printf" in HelloWorld.c? I don't think you quite understand my problem.

Comment: He is getting a warning about the system include files(stdlib.h) if I understand right, not in his own code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize those functions were not self-written because I only write C99 code and have never used them. Edited my answer.

Comment: `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` is the correct portable way to do this. `-D_GNU_SOURCE` is glibc-specific.

Comment: My only beef with this answer is that I believe the definition should go in the source file itself (the very first thing in any source file), not on the command line. After all, it is the source code itself that requires the features enabled by the POSIX feature test macros, not the build environment. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting makes it sound like the functions you're using aren't being declared. Are you sure you're including the correct headers for them?

Also, using `-std=c99` may disable some extensions which are not part of the standard. None of the functions you mentioned are part of the C standard. If you can't find separate headers for them, you might try `-std=gnu99`.

Answer (score 2):

`-std=c99` causes the headers to omit anything that could clash with uses of names outside the C99 reserved namespace, including all standard POSIX functions. The portable way to request the headers give you the POSIX interfaces is to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to a value corresponding to the desired POSIX version. For the latest POSIX (2008), this means:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

or on the command line:

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

**Edit:** It seems the functions you want are not in the POSIX base but in the XSI option, so you should define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to an appropriate value (`700` is the latest) to get them. This too can be done from the command line or your source files (but if from the source files, it must be done **before** including any system headers.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit declarations (where an undeclared function is assumed to return int) are no longer allowed in C99.

That said, gcc will not abort the compilation.

Try to include `strings.h` for `bzero`, see also paxdiablo's answer.

Comment: I think this is what happening: nothing's actually *different*, but the implicit function definitions just aren't being reported without c99's standards. Which means my #includes simply aren't working for whatever reason. Hell...

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for standards compliance, and [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) doesn't define `srand48()` as a function provided by `<stdlib.h>`.

For the GNU C library, you can request additional features by defining one or more of the options listed in the comment at the top of `/usr/include/features.h`, either by `#define` before you `#include`, or with `-D` flag to `gcc`.

For `srand48()` (and `drand48()`) you probably want either `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` or `-D_SVID_SOURCE` (or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` etc. in the source files).

`bzero()` and `close()` should work even with `-std=c99` if you `#include` the documented header files for them, which are `<strings.h>` and `<unistd.h>` respectively.