# What could make sys/types.h's id_t not be declared?

Tags: c, types, acl

I have a C file which is exhibiting some strange behavior. When I use `id_t`, the compiler claims it's not defined (it's defined in `sys/types.h`). Here's what's weird: I include `sys/acl.h`, which in turn includes `sys/types.h`. In the `sys/acl.h` header file itself, `id_t` is referenced, and the compiler doesn't complain about that. Further, when I remove my reference to it, the entire thing compiles properly, implying that the compiler hit `sys/acl.h`'s use of `id_t` and didn't have a problem with it. Any idea what could be going on?

**EDIT**: `sys/acl.h` uses `id_t` in a define, which means it's not actually getting used; my bad on that one.

**EDIT**: using `gcc -E` (thanks for the tip, @kaylum), I figured out that the definition isn't getting included in the build. It's surrounded by the following guards:

```
#if (defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_XOPEN || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8) \
    && !defined __id_t_defined
typedef __id_t id_t;
# define __id_t_defined
#endif
```

I tried using `-D__USE_SVID`, and it did nothing. I also tried adding `#define __USE_SVID` above the include statement, and it also did nothing.

**EDIT**: Figured it out; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893443/836390) to another SO question. I switched to using `-std=gnu99` (from `-std=c99`) and it worked.

Comment: You have it. Can you show it to us?

Comment: Sorry, what's "it" here?

Comment: What is your compiler? If gcc then use the `-E` option to produce preprocessed output which should give you a clearer idea what is going on.

Comment: So it turns out `sys/acl.h` doesn't actually use it - it only uses it in a define, and since that define isn't used, there's nothing to complain about. I confirmed the issue by using the define in my code; the compiler complained.

Comment: As for the preprocessor output, you're right - the line isn't included.

Comment: @joshlf I actually meant to look at the preprocessor output to see whether `id_t` is indeed defined. In `sys/types.h` the `id_t` definition is conditionally defined. On my system: `#if (defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_XOPEN || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8)`. I don't know what all those conditions really represent but perhaps on your system they are all false for some reason.

Comment: @joshlf “It” is the source code in question.