# Casting result from random() to int causes GCC to say "warning: implicit function definition". Why?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, gcc-warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t gcc find the random() interface when -std=c99 is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575350/why-cant-gcc-find-the-random-interface-when-std-c99-is-set)

I'm new to C, so I just went into `man stdlib.h`, searched for "random", saw that `random()` returned `long`, and, because it's just a learning exercise, thought I'd just cast to int (instead of bothering to look up one which returns `int` - `rand()` is the one).

Anyway, the program compiles and runs correctly. But:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 part1.c
part1.c: In function 'main':
part1.c:44:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'random'
```

It goes away if I remove the `-std=99` flag. Here is the "offending" code:

```
  int test6[1000];
  for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    test6[i] = (int) random();
    printf("it is %d\n", test6[i]); //check random() is working (it isn't seeded)
  }
  printf("%d\n", largest(test6, 1000));
```

So I just wondered if anyone knew why this was, as I thought it might be interesting.

Answer (score 6):

You get the `warning: implicit function definition` message because the function `random()` isn't declared before you use it.  It isn't a standard C function (not in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 or its predecessor versions).  You'll need to know which header declares it; you might need to `#define` something to make the declaration visible.

In C99, you have to declare all functions before using them; that's why the `-std=c99` mode objects (though having issued the mandatory diagnostic, it can continue to compile, probably making the backwards-compatible assumption that the function returns an `int`).  In older versions of C, you did not have to pre-declare functions; undeclared functions were implicitly declared as `extern int function();`, which means 'a function with unspecified (but not variable) argument list that returns an `int`'.  That's why the compilation continues making that assumption; it used to be the standard assumption to make.  With C99 and C2011, it is officially an error.

---

> My confusion is that the program still compiles and runs correctly though (`random()` does return pseudorandoms as well)! I have `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of the file. Is it possible that my `#include` isn't working, but `make` is doing something clever to work out where to get it? The other thing (which I forgot to put in the question), is that, I thought, the warning initially disappeared when I removed the cast to `int`. I can't replicate that though, so I guess there must be some other explanation for it. Perhaps I accidentally removed the `-std=c99` from the `makefile` or something.

I said 'Standard C does not define it'; it doesn't, but [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) does.  So, by including the correct header (which is `<stdlib.h>`), and by ensuring that the declaration is seen, the function is picked up from the C library (which is not a pure Standard C library, but rather contains a lot of POSIX functions too, and a lot of other functions specific to GLIBC).  So, it works because the libraries contain the function.  You may want/need to compile with `-std=gnu99` or specify `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` or something similar (before you include any system headers) to get the declaration of `random()` visible under `-std=c99`.  I use a header `posixver.h` to get the information into my programs.

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: posixver.h,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.1 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2010/08/29 00:27:48 $
@(#)Purpose:        Request appropriate POSIX and X/Open Support
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
*/

#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2001 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600   /* SUS v3, POSIX 1003.1 2004 (POSIX 2001 + Corrigenda) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

This is rather conservative and doesn't request POSIX 2008 support because some of the machines I work on don't have that available — still!  You can use it as a basis for your version which can be more aggressive if you prefer.  I used to have the stanza directly in the programs, but that becomes a nightmare to fix when it is safe to change to POSIX 2008 (and maintaining the comments sensibly in many source files would have been plain silly — so the files usually contained just `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600` with minimal or no commentary, but it is still a fiddle to change when the time comes to change).

Comment: OK, my confusion is that the program still compiles and runs correctly though (`random()` does return pseudorandoms as well)! I have `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of the file. Is it possible that my #include isn't working, but `make` is doing something clever to work out where to get it?


The other thing (which I forgot to put in the question), is that, I thought, the warning initially disappeared when I removed the cast to int. I can't replicate that though, so I guess there must be some other explanation for it. Perhaps I accidentally removed the -std=c99 from the makefile or something.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get rid of the error.

Comment: @TomášZato: what have you tried?  Have you looked at the duplicate?  There are multiple solutions, but maybe you should ask a new question with an MCVE ([MCVE]) which should be quite short — less than twenty lines of code. Identify your platform and compiler and versions thereof and the command line you're using.  Include a link to this or the duplicate. If you wish, leave a comment here linking to the new question.